# How to run This Observable asynchronously?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have the following service which imitates some blocking IO operation:

```
public class StudentService{

public List<Student> getStudentAslist(){

            Thread.sleep(10000);
.....
        return students;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to run this service inside `FutureTask<T>` using Java 8 environment:

```
     StudentService studentService = new StudentService();  
     FutureTask<List<Student>> future = new FutureTask<>(()-> studentService.getStudentAslist());

     Worker worker = Schedulers.io().createWorker();
            worker.schedule(()->future.run());


     Observable<Student> observable2 = Observable.from(future).flatMap(Observable::from);
    observable2.filter((s)-> s.getAge()>40).subscribe(student->System.out.println(student));

    System.out.println("end");
```

However the final print "end" gets printed only after 10 seconds, so it seems like i'm totally synchronous,

How can I run it reactively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `.subscribeOn`

```
FutureTask<List<String>> future = new FutureTask<>(this::getStudentAslist);

Scheduler.Worker worker = Schedulers.io().createWorker();
worker.schedule(future::run);

Observable.from(future)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .flatMapIterable(s -> s)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
System.out.println("marker");


TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
```

For reference :

```
public List<String> getStudentAslist(){
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return Collections.singletonList("finished");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use *defer* to move all work into Observable

```
FutureTask<List<String>> future = new FutureTask<>(this::getStudentAslist);

Observable<List<Student>> studentsObservable = Observable
        .defer(() -> {
            future.run();
            return Observable.from(future);
        });
```

and then use *subscribeOn* to decide which thread will be used for this Observable

```
studentsObservable
        .flatMapIterable(students -> students)
        .filter((s) -> s.getAge() > 40)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(student -> System.out.println(student));
```